# .htaccess with 2 rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 diff strings:

index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2
index.php?abrir=$1&livro=$2

id= and livro= so I'm trying using this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1&id=$2&pagina=$3

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1&livro=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?abrir=$1&livro=$2&pagina=$3
```

But only the first work... How I can resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matching patterns in your rewrite rules for abrir=.. and livro=.. are identical. The first rewrite rule in a .htaccess file that matches for the current request is used. So if you have two identical rewrite rules only the one that occurs first in your .htaccess file will work.

Comment: What will be the actual difference between the values for id and livro? You should have some way to determine whether it is an id value or a livro value. If it is something like numbers vs strings than you can fix it in the .htaccess file, otherwise it will probably be easier to create one rewrite rule and determine the difference in your code.

Comment: You want to rewrite an URL in the formats /part1/part2 or /part1/part2/part3 to another URL. Which values for part2 should match for your first set of rules, and which values should match for your second set of rules? E.g. the values "car" and "bike" should match for id= and the values "apple" and "pear" should match for livro=.

Comment: all values of id and livro is numbers...the diff is the pages, I use id= in profile page, etc... and livro= in some pages that I use a system...

Comment: And how do you determine which number is an id and which number is livro? There must be some way to determine this, otherwise there is no valid reason for the difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4489/discussion-between-jan-henk-and-gtokai)